# Change element layout when it has to flex-wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create social media links and have them start out aligned. When they start wrapping, I want it to line up the links in a zig zag pattern. For example, if there are 5 links and the window is small where they have to wrap, the position of the links will go from a line to a "W" shape.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  padding: 4em;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.c-socials__list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.c-socials__list__item {
  padding: 0 0.5em;
}
.c-socials__list__item a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  background-color: #353535;
  padding: 1.25em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
}
.c-socials__list__item a:hover, .c-socials__list__item a:focus {
  background-color: red;
}

.u-list-unstyled {
  list-style: none !important;
}

.u-list-horizontal > * {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="c-socials">
    <ul class="u-list-unstyled u-list-horizontal c-socials__list">
      <li class="c-socials__list__item"><a href="#">hi</a></li>
      <li class="c-socials__list__item"><a href="#">hi</a></li>
      <li class="c-socials__list__item"><a href="#">hi</a></li>
      <li class="c-socials__list__item"><a href="#">hi</a></li>
      <li class="c-socials__list__item"><a href="#">hi</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: I am ok with moving to a different direction or using javascript to adjust the layout if it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

i think add class name, and adding position there, but you have to set it up well to be responsive, i hope this is help you my friend

```css
.container {
    max-width: 400px;
    min-height: 100vh;
    padding: 4em;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }


  .c-socials__list {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding-left: 20;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
  }
  .c-socials__list__item {
    padding: 0 0.5em;
  }
  .c-socials__list__item a {
  
    color: white;
    background-color: #353535;
    padding: 1.25em;
    border-radius: 50%;
    transition: background-color 300ms ease-out;
  }
  .c-socials__list__item a:hover, .c-socials__list__item a:focus {
    background-color: red;
  }
  
  .u-list-unstyled {
    list-style: none !important;
  }
  
  .u-list-horizontal > * {
    display: inline-block !important;
  }
  
  .zig-zag {
    margin-right: 40px;
  }

  .zig-zag  a{
      position: absolute;
      top: 60px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="c-socials">
          <ul class="u-list-unstyled u-list-horizontal c-socials__list">
            <li class="c-socials__list__item"><a href="#">hi</a></li>
            <li class="c-socials__list__item zig-zag"><a href="#">hi</a></li>
            <li class="c-socials__list__item"><a href="#">hi</a></li>
            <li class="c-socials__list__item zig-zag"><a href="#">hi</a></li>
            <li class="c-socials__list__item"><a href="#">hi</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```